# Async validation never returns in loopback

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

I have an `async` validation in one of my models in which I query for a related object to validate it's existence. The problem is that the request is timing out on this validation and the server never responds.

```
module.exports = function(Ip) {
      // Required fields
      Ip.validatesPresenceOf('server_id');

      ...

      Ip.validateAsync('server_id', isExistingServer, {
            message: 'invalid server'
      });

      function isExistingServer(err, done) {
            var ServerModel = Ip.app.models.Server;
            var self = this;
            process.nextTick(function() {
                  ServerModel.findById(self.server_id, function(e, server) {
                        console.log(_.isNull(server));// this actually prints false
                        return _.isNull(server) ? err() : done();
                  });
            });
      }
};
```

Comment: may be use async.series

Comment: Hi romeo , did you find a soluton. I also experience that this hangs my process. ChecklistItem.validatesPresenceOf('checklistId', 'checklistItemCategoryId');

Answer (score 3):

Because you need execute `done();` then `err();`

Answer (score 2):

According to [documentation](https://apidocs.strongloop.com/loopback-datasource-juggler/v/2.54.0/#validatable-validateasync) you should call `done()` after `err`. This is the example in docs:

```
User.validateAsync('name', customValidator, {message: 'Bad name'});

function customValidator(err, done) {
    process.nextTick(function () {
        if (this.name === 'bad') err();
        done();
    });
});
```

Note that as there is no return before the call to `err()`, `done` will also be called.